# Como criar rotas privadas no React JS com Firebase?

Tags: react, firebase, firestore, react-router-dom

estou com o seguinte problema.
Estou criando um sistema com React JS e Firebase no qual tem dois tipos de usuários, e eu gostaria de criar rotas específicas para cada um deles. (Usuário comum e Administrador)

Mas, como fazer isso da melhor forma?
O meu sistema de login funciona perfeitamente, só me perdi nessa hora de dividir as rotas.

Segue meu arquivo **Routes.jsx**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../../firebase-config.js';
import { root } from '../../index.js';
import React from 'react';
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Login from '../Login/Login';
import MeuPerfil from '../MeuPerfil/MeuPerfil';
import Suporte from '../Suporte/Suporte';
import RedefinirSenha from '../RedefinirSenha/RedefinirSenha';

//Admin Imports
import AdminDashboard from '../Admin/Dashboard/Dashboard';

export default function Rotas(props) {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (props.admin === false) {
            root.render(
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
                        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
                        <Route path="/suporte" element={<Suporte />} />
                        <Route path="/perfil" element={<MeuPerfil />} />
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            );
        } else if (props.admin === true) {
            root.render(
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
                        <Route path="/" element={<AdminDashboard />} />
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            );
        
        } else {
            root.render(
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
                        <Route path="/esqueci-a-senha" element={<RedefinirSenha />} />
                        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Segue meu arquivo **BuscaDados.jsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase-config';
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

export default async function BuscarDados(){
    const [infoUsers, setInfoUsers] = useState([])
    
    const values = async () => {
        const email = await localStorage.getItem("userEmail");
        const q = await query(collection(db, "clientes_contabilidade"), where("email", "==", email));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        setInfoUsers(await querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        values()
    }, [])
}
```

Segue meu arquivo **App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Rotas from './Routes';
import BuscarDados from '../../services/BuscarDados';

export default function App() {
  const admin = BuscarDados()
  return(
    <div className="App">
      <Rotas admin={admin}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Basicamente, o que eu tentei fazer é, no momento do login, armazenar o email do usuário no `localStorage()`, e depois acessar esse parametro no arquivo **App.jsx** salvando o dado em uma `const admin = BuscarDados()` e por fim, passar essa constante, no arquivo do Routes, para tentar fazer o direcionamento de acordo com o valor dessa constante.

Um ponto importante, a `const Admin` é sempre um valor boleano (True ou False).

Alguém pode me dar um norte, por que não funciona?

Answer (score -1):

Em cada rota dentro de `element` você coloca um componente que faz a autenticação ou verificação do usuário e nesse elemento você retorna o children caso dê sucesso ou você retorna um redirect/navigate caso a autenticação falhe. Exemplo:

```
export const CheckRoute = ({ admin, children }) => {


    // seu código para autenticação e checar se o usuário pode usar essa rota
    const user = { admin: false }

    return (!admin || (admin && user.admin)) ? children : <Redirect to="/login">

}
```

E depois aplica o mesmo as rotas:

```
<Route path="/suporte" element={<CheckRoute admin={true}><Suporte /></CheckRoute>}
<Route path="/perfil" element={<CheckRoute admin={false}><MeuPerfil /></CheckRoute>} />
```

Nesse caso a rota de perfil deixaria ele seguir a navegação e na rota de suporte ele seria redirecionado para a tela de login